# XAP files for silverlight 4

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight-4.0, xap

Can you imbed silverlight 4 xap files into an aspx page and then view them in vs 2008? If so how do you do this? Any sample code would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not?  Simply add the XAP to your ASP.NET web project and add an  tag to your ASPX.  Here's the basic embed for a Silverlight app:

```
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/MyApp.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object>
```

Comment: so even though you wouldn't be able to edit the silverlight 4 xaml code in vs2008, you'd still be able to view the xap output in an aspx file within vs2008 environment? i.e. i'm wondering if i could use web developer 2010 to develop my silverlight 4 xap files, then debug in my aspx website in vs 2008

Comment: Yes.  In VS 2008 you can add a xap much like an image, video, html file, etc.  Then in your aspx page use the <object> embed.  Additionally, you CAN use VS Web Developer 2010 create Silverlight 4 apps.  Now, if you want to debug the Silverlight code, you'll need to do so from VS 2010.  Debugging the ASP.NET project you'll use VS2008.